# knockout.js options binding not reflecting added item

Tags: knockout.js

The page shows the original list of advisers properly.  However, when I attempt to use the push() method into the array, the list size updates, but the select option list on the page does not update. Do I need to tell knockout to update or something? Here is some sample code:

```
function updateStudentAdviserList(student) {
    var list = viewModel.studentAdvisers();    
    if (student.IsStudentAdviser() == "true" || student.IsStudentAdviser() == true) {
        var alreadyInList = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            alert(list[i].Id);
            if (list[i].Id == student.Id()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        list.push(student);
        alert('new size: ' + list.length);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            alert(list[i].Id);
            if (list[i].Id == student.Id()) {
                list.splice(i, 1);
                alert('new size: ' + list.length);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
function ViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;    
    this.studentAdvisers = ko.observableArray(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made changes to `js` array not to `observableArray`. You have to notify `knockout` about the changes. You can call `valueHasMutated` for this.

```
function updateStudentAdviserList(student) {
    var list = viewModel.studentAdvisers();    
    if (student.IsStudentAdviser() == "true" || student.IsStudentAdviser() == true) {
        var alreadyInList = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            alert(list[i].Id);
            if (list[i].Id == student.Id()) {
                return;
            }
        }

        list.push(student);
        alert('new size: ' + list.length);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            alert(list[i].Id);
            if (list[i].Id == student.Id()) {
                list.splice(i, 1);
                alert('new size: ' + list.length);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    viewModel.studentAdvisers.valueHasMutated();
}
```

Comment: This definitely worked! Thanks! Why did I have to do this though?

Comment: Because when you call this: var list = viewModel.studentAdvisers(); You get js array and knockout doesn't know what happen with it. To avoid callig valueHasMutated you should call push function directly from  viewModel.studentAdvisers - viewModel.studentAdvisers.push(NewValue)

Comment: I tried it without setting it to a variable "list" and it still required the valueHasMutated() though.

Comment: Did you try  viewModel.studentAdvisers.push or  viewModel.studentAdvisers().push? It should be without brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Observable arrays have the same methods as regular arrays, so if you use:

```
viewModel.studentAdvisers.push(student)
```

instead of:

```
list.push(student);
```

and the same with splice, knockout will be notify with changes.